What kind of bug it is?
I saw dozens of this bug in my kitchen. They are smaller than one millimeter and they crawl and jump. Can someone help me please. Thanks 

Welcome mohammad. Could you add the detail of your location for reference.

Thanks. I live in Iran, Tehran.
